# Conditional Probability and Random testing.

Tags: probability, statistics

Say that there are two factories producing light bulbs. Factory X produces 40% of all light bulbs and Factory Y produces the other 60%. The defective rate for lightbulbs is 2% for Factory X and 15% for Factory Y. Naturally if a lightbulb from a batch of unknown origin is selected at random and is found to be defective we can use Bayes theorem to find the new probability that the batch was manufactured by Company X or Company Y.

So now my question has to do with random testing of the light bulbs. Does it affect anything if instead of selecting 1 at random and finding it defective we have to test 30 until we find a defective one. Intuitively I feel that the amount of light bulbs we test until finding a defective one would affect the probability that it came from a certain factory. For example lets say that we have a batch of 1000 light bulbs and we have to randomly test 500 of them (it's a lot I know) until we find a defective one. Such an example would lead me to believe that it is a lot more likely that the bulbs were produced by Factory X than Factory Y. Yet using the above probabilities as they are (2% and 15%), Bayes theorem would most probably tell me that the bulb came from factory Y. This seems wrong.

Comment: In your second example, the observation is not "the tested lightbulb was defective" but "499 satisfactory lightbulbs were tested, followed by a defective one" and that changes the likelihood considerably

Comment: Perhaps you should try to do the calculations and see if Bayes' theorem tells you that the bulb came from factory Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all 30 bulbs are from the same batch, then you can absolutely take that into account. Your statistic is $X = $ the number of bulbs tested before finding a faulty bulb, and if the probability of finding a faulty bulb is $p$ then $X \sim Geom(p)$ has a geometric distribution, and so you can express $P(X = x | p)$, the probability of testing $x$ good bulbs given a certain value of $p$, and hence you can apply Bayes' Theorem to find $P(p | X = x)$, i.e. the probability that the failure rate is $p$ given the number of good bulbs tested.